# Why is there no command line to find python location?

Tags: python, windows

I can find python version with `python --version`
But I cannot find the location of python executable. Is there a command like `python --path`? If not, is there a reason why?

Comment: `where python` on Windows, `which python` of Linux

Answer (score 3):

Use [`sys.executable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.executable):

```
python -c 'import sys; print(sys.executable)'
```

Comment: That's clever, going to have to remember that one.

Answer (score 2):

use 'where python' in your terminal to get the path to it

**edit**

`where python` works for windows and `which python` works for linux

Answer (score 0):

Use `which python` or `which python3`.
Work on unix based OS.

For Windows, see other answers.

Comment: which isn't recognised ?

Comment: em, what do you mean?

Comment: @MaxDavies that's right, `which` is for Linux.

Comment: @MarkRansom I see, it was not clear to me what are the OPs specs :)

Comment: @FilipNiko it's well hidden, one of the question tags is `windows`.

Comment: @MarkRansom thats true, however he can still use WSL `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`. But I think answers were given.

Comment: Under WSL you might get a different answer, they needn't have the same PATH.

Comment: Not using windows, so not gonna argue about that :))

Answer (score 0):

(Note:  the `which` and `ls -l` commands won't work on Windows, but the general tracking of where Python has been installed on the file system **should** still be available in `sys.base_prefix`)

To elaborate a bit on Wim's answer (I nosed around in the sys namespace before seeing their answer) there are different possible "pythons" you might be interested in:  the `which python` location.  (or in Windows terms, where does it first see `python` in a %PATH% location?)

Also you might be interested to know: **where is python actually installed on the file system?**

`sys.base_prefix` helps with the latter.

`python -c 'import sys; print(f"{sys.executable=}\n{sys.base_prefix=}" )'`

Without an activated virtualenv, I get this on macos using a macport-based python:

```
sys.executable='/opt/local/bin/python'
sys.base_prefix='/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10'
```

And in fact if you dig into what's on in that bin directory, you find:

```
% ls -l /opt/local/bin/python
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  25  7 Jan  2022 /opt/local/bin/python -> /opt/local/bin/python3.10
```

and

```
% ls -l /opt/local/bin/python3.10
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  admin  75  7 Jun 02:02 /opt/local/bin/python3.10 -> /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/bin/python3.10
```

So the actual installed binary is under the location of `base_prefix`.

If I activate my virtual environment, `base_prefix` stays the same, but the `sys.executable` reflects the fact that I am now in a virtualenv

```
sys.executable='/Users/me/kds2/venvs/bme/bin/python'
sys.base_prefix='/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10'
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to the proposed probing in `sys`, one could also opt to use the builtin `shutil.which` that returns whatever the OS returns for calls being made. As a free bonus, it's a cross-platform oneliner that guarantees the same path as the system would return in the same environment.

```bash
$ python -c "from shutil import which; print(which('python'))"
C:\Program Files\Python310\python.EXE  # windows
C:\msys64\mingw64\bin/python.EXE  # MSYS2 on Windows
```